# EntityFramework, should I use Inheritance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following model, without using inheritance:

Question class:

```
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionTitle { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public int questionType { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<TextAnswer> TextAnswers { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ParagraphAnswer> ParagraphAnswers { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<Choice> Choices { get; set; }
    [ScriptIgnore]
    public virtual ICollection<ChoiceAnswer> ChoiceAnswers { get; set; }
```

Should I use inheritance for the answers?
That is,

```
TextAnswer : Answer
ParagraphAnswer : Answer
ChoiceAnswer : Answer
```

so that the Question class have only one ICollection ?

What would you suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the proper way to model this is with inheritance.

Note that you have some choices of how inheritance is mapped to tables (TPH, TPT) and with complex, multilevel hierarchies you may want to keep an eye on performance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. That's the advantage of Inheritance in JAVA. Through this approach you'll achieve good design for your code.

Your code will be open for new enhancements and extensions with less code changes, since base class alone will be extended for any new ANSWER class and there won't be no changes needed in question class.

Comment: This is true for general OOP principals, but this question is about C# in the context of Entity Framework.

Answer (score -2):

My experience with inheritance and entity framework is rather poor. In specific cases (I don't want to go too much into details here) queries produced by EF had like 1Mb in size.. (I'm not talking about the results - just query text!)

Recently (about 6 months) I've started using NHibernate. In my company we have a software that is developed as a product - which means at least 3-4 levels of inheritance for each entity. NHibernate copes really well with it - you might want to give it a try.

As to EF: no don't use inheritance. This project is not mature enough.

//edit because of downvotes:
I've been using Entity Framework from the first release including hardcore things like writing custom "Custom Tool" for Visual Studio to generate code from EDMX files. The custom generator added support for stored procedures and proper lazy loading (which was broken in EF 1.0) and some more.

Then came EF 2.0 and huge changes. I've used EF in several projects. In one of them we had a requirement that all entities have one base class. This was hardcore hacking once again and this was when the case with huge query text occured. If you want to downvote my answer once again feel free to do it, but just because your case wasn't that complicated (if we can call having a base class a complicated case anyway..) doesn't mean that EF is a mature and stable ORM.

Comment: Add least add version numbers and some indication of he model.

Comment: I'm planning on using TPH on the Questions (TextQuestion, ChoicesQuestion, ..) and TPT on the Answers

Comment: This _may_ have been true with the early versions of EF, but I have had a great experience with inheritance in EF 4.x.

Comment: just because your case was that (over-)complicated  doesn't mean that EF is not a mature and stable ORM.

Comment: Having a base class for your entities is a must in almost all enterprise applications.. In a current project this is a must because every entity has version(optimistic concurrency) and audit fields createdon, createdby, modifiedon, modifiedby. Is that a very complicated case?